Which functions of skin cells have scientists been able to revert 30 years?
According to this article Scientists discover new method to reverse ageing in human skill cells by 30 years (and several others from 2022-2024)

"Researchers said they have been able to partly restore the function
of older cells, as well as renew the biological age."

Which functions of skin cells have scientists been able to revert 30 years?

You'll notice the telomeres were not lengthened by the process.

The original scientific article >accessible here< mentions rejuvenation of cell attributes such as displaying a 30 year-younger transcriptome, statement reached through comparing to a reference data set. So such rewind of the cellular biological clock by around 30 years is then established according to molecular measures. The functional analyses involved properties such as wound healing simulation experiments (in vitro migration speed) commonly associated and displayed by skin cells.
Due to technical advances that allow researchers to measure age-related biological changes in human cells and through their method based on the Nobel Prize-winning technique to make stem cells, using a shorter-timed version (13 instead of 50 day exposure), these researchers were able to reset ageing indicators in genes associated with diseases and restore cells to a more youthful state, regaining their specialised function to an improved potential, and overall reversing ageing as the gradual decline in cellular functions, which is normally considered irreversible at "senescence" state.
The aspiration would be to identify genes that rejuvenate without a full reprogramming or erasing cellular memory identity, and specifically target those to reduce the effects of ageing, an approach that holds promise for valuable discoveries in the therapeutic horizon.
For a complementary and holistic view perhaps, an alternative article from a lay magazine (with elaborate text and without typos unlike the one cited by OP) can be accessed >here<.

did you say one of the properties they restore was being able to heal like younger cells? Or did I get that wrong?

yes - experimentalists test "wound healing" simulated on a petri dish with a layer of cells deliberately scratched and then cell movement monitored over time by camera captures (in incubating conditions), tracking how long it takes for the cells to migrate and seal the gap, the speed is the factor compared.
